# body onload function undefined after using require js

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I moved all my javascript files loading to require js.

```
</head>
<body onLoad="main()">
```

I get the error that main is undefined. Not everytime, but once in every couple of runs.

I have defined main in one of  my js files which is included using require js.

Comment: make sure path is correct..

Comment: is require.js in head or in body tag?

Comment: it is finding main most of the times, but only some times Its not loading that js file which has main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If main is defined using Require, it is loaded asynchronously. This means that it may or may not exist at body onLoad time. Thus the error.

You don't need onLoad. The entry point of your application is the callback function to *the single* call to `require()`:

```
require(["dep1", "dep2"], function(dep1, dep2) {
    // code here is essentially your main
})
```